# Show images/css using GAE with Django

Tags: css, django, image, google-app-engine

I'm confused about the exposure of css files and images on my project. There are lot of samples using django or but I can't find something for a combined case. If anyone could help, I'll be thankful.

Comment: What makes you think it's any different from any other GAE site?

Comment: I saw two different approaches for the same thing. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ and http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers

Comment: Maybe gae's setup works up on django's or parallel. But what is the final uri for an image which is located to http://localhost:8080/templates/images/background.jpg ?

Comment: Ok, finally I managed to display both images and css files. GAE Launcher Logs helps to see in which path application tries to find your static file. I made changes only in app.yaml

Answer (score 0):

1. I use variables `static_dir` and `static_files` with app.yaml:

   `- url: /static`

   ```
       static_dir: static
   ```

   `- url: /stylesheets/main.css`

   ```
       static_files: stylesheets/main.css
   ```
2. Another method you could use is upload your images to the blobstore and serve from there.